# How to setup basic auth for Prometheus deployed on K8s cluster using yamls?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

How to setup basic auth for Prometheus deployed on K8s cluster using yamls??

I was able to achieve this easily when Prometheus was deployed on a host locally using tar file. But when it is deployed as a pod in K8s cluster, tried almost everything on the internet but no luck.

Any kind of help would be really appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the required annotations to the ingress as required.For nginx, you can follow [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/main/docs/examples/auth/basic)